# Acrobat XI add text from Excel spreadsheet to multiple different PDF pages

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I need to add QTY and Note fields to multiple independent pdfs

Example: 
PDF#1 needs to add QTY and Note Text from Part #1's Row
PDF#2 needs to add QTY and Note Text from Part #2's Row
ETC.

I tried to use a mail merge plugin but all that did was create a binder with PDF#1 with text from all 50 rows 
then a binder with PDF#2 with text from all 50 rows
ETC.

There's 50 PDFs in this job and I get this type of job often so I'd like to stream line the process

Thanks for the help and sorry for the poorly worded question, it's my first time on a forum like this